# Gibbs information and information theory

Tags: statistical-mechanics, probability, information, partition-function

In the study of statistics, a given family of probability densities depending smoothly upon a parameter $\theta$ can be expressed in the form

$p(x,\theta)=exp\left[c(x)+\sum_{r}\theta^{r}S_{r}(x)-\psi(\theta)\right],$

where the variable $x$ ranges over the sample space.

In models of statistical mechanics, we generally deal with Gibbs measures in the form

$p(x,\theta)=exp\left[\sum_{r}\theta^{r}S_{r}(x)-ln(\psi(\theta))\right],$

where the $S_{r}$ determines the form of the action and $\psi(\theta)=lnZ(\theta)$ is gibbs free energy,
and $Z$ the partition function.

Based on the above, what is the meaning of $x$ in $Z$?

Comment: There is no $x$ in your $Z$.

Comment: Hi @NDewolf, I have just updated the question. Tell me if you see it

Comment: It's not true you can write any distribution in this form, this is only true for *exponential family*  of distributions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family

Comment: Hi @Andrew. Ok, I see your point. However, what is the meaning of $x$ in $Z$?

Comment: Can you give an example? In the context of Bayesian inference, normally $\theta$ would refer to some parameters and $x$ to observed data. In statistical mechanics I would guess the $\theta$ are playing the role of Lagrange multipliers (inverse temperature, chemical potential...) and the $x$ are quantities the system could exchange with its environment (energy, number of particles, ...). But it would help to see an example or have more context.

Comment: Hi @Andrew. My question is related to the paper "Geometrical aspects of statistical mechanics" Physical Review E, 1995, volume 51, number 2. A few examples are discussed in this paper. However, the probability distributions that authors consider do not show any dependence on $x$.

Comment: gibs is actually spelled "Gibbs". Two b's, one s and starting with a capital G. Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josiah_Willard_Gibbs

Comment: There still is no $x$ in $Z$.

Comment: Hi @my2cts, thanks for commenting!

Answer (score 0):

Eq. 2 of Ref [1] (which is by the same first author as Ref [2], which the OP mentioned in the comments) defines the Gibbs measure for the canonical ensemble
\begin{equation}
p(H,\beta) = q(x) \exp\left[-\beta H(x)-W(\beta)\right]
\end{equation}
**where $x$ ranges over configuration space**, $H(x)$ is the energy, $\beta=1/kT$ is the inverse temperature, and $W(\beta)$ is a normalization constant.

Let's compare this with the normal way to write Boltzman distribution. The Boltzman distribution gives the probability of finding the system in a given microstate, which is determined by the configuration space variables $x$.
\begin{equation}
p(x,\beta) =\frac{e^{-\beta H(x)}}{\int dx e^{-\beta H(x)}} = \frac{e^{-\beta H(x)}}{Z}
\end{equation}
where the partition function is $Z\equiv \int dx e^{-\beta H(x)}$.

It should be understood that $x$ here is not necessarily a single variable, but in general could be a vector of parameters. For instance, $x$ could represent the positions and momenta of $10^{23}$ particles, and in this case $\int dx$ really should be understood as a huge integral over each of these $10^{23}$ configuration space variables.

Now this isn't quite the same thing as Eq 2, which gives the probability of the system having a certain *energy* $H$, rather than being in a given microstate labelled by $x$.

To convert, we need to include a factor of the *density of states* $\rho(H)$. This function tells us how many states $\rho(H)d H$ have an energy in the interval from $H$ to $H+dH$.

\begin{equation}
p(H,\beta) = \frac{\rho(H) e^{-\beta H}}{Z} = \rho(H) \exp\left[-\beta H - \log Z\right]
\end{equation}

Comparing this expression with the first one, we can identify the normalization $W(\beta)$  with the log of the partition function $Z$

\begin{equation}
W(\beta) = \log Z
\end{equation}

Now it appears that the function $q(x)$ in the high temperature $\beta\rightarrow 0$ limit is related to the density of states
\begin{equation}
q(x) \equiv \rho(H(x))
\end{equation}
**To be honest I don't understand the notation $q(x)$**, because each microstate should be equally likely in the high temperature limit. So I am not sure if the author is intending a distribution of microstates that violates the assumption that each accessible microstate is equally likely, or if $q(x)$ is meant to include some coarse graining over some subset of microstates, or something else.

References:

[1] https://cds.cern.ch/record/332060/files/9708032.pdf

[2] "Geometrical aspects of statistical mechanics" Physical Review E, 1995, volume 51, number 2.

Comment: Hi @Andrew! Thanks for the clarifying answer!. In the light of the foregoing, what is the meaning of $x$ in $Z$?

Comment: @ViniciusHolmes $x$ ranges over the configuration space, so in a gas it might label the positions and momenta of $10^{23}$ particles. The partition function $Z$ involves an integral over configuration space, so in the gas example $\int dx$ would be a multi-dimensional integral over all the positions and momenta (so integrating over a space with an enormous number of dimensions).

Comment: Now, I see your point @Andrew. However, the partition function of reference [2] seems to be independent of $x$ in the examples discussed in the paper. Is that correct?

Comment: @ViniciusHolmes The partition function is an integral over $x$ so therefore doesn't depend on $x$. Much like $Z=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx e^{-x^2/2}=\sqrt{2\pi}$ doesn't depend on $x$.